# how to connect to another host which has windows operating system by .net c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, openssh, ssh.net

I want to connect to a host which has windows operating system and then run some commands in that computer. generally I have try two solutions :

1. I installed **openSSh** on both computers then used ssh command to
   connect to the host in CMD and it was successfull (this was done in
   order to  become sure that I can connect) then I used SSH.net
   library to SSh to that host in Visual Studio but it didn't connect
   and the error was **"an established connection was aborted by the
   software in your host machine "** (I read all question about this
   error) . I think this error comes because ssh.net library is
   written for linux connections and not windows. am I right?
2. I read about **WMI** (windows management instrumentation) and try to create connection first by windows PowerShell
   (again to become sure that there isn't any problem). I
   have done many actions to solve the problem "accessing deny" (like check firewall, security access and permission, run some commands in windows power shell)
   but it hasn't solved yet.(I almost read all question about this problem). I have try this code in my application but exception comes.

   ```cs
   ip = "172.17.9.2";
   username = "****";
   password = "***";
   port = 22 ;
   var processToRun = new[] { "notepad.exe" };
   var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
   connection.Username = username;
   connection.Password = password;
   var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", "FB"), connection);
   var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
       wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
   ```

I spend a lot of time on WMI to understand what problem is. Now I'm looking for another way which is simple and easy to implement.

Comment: You really should try [PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/schlepticons/2012/03/23/powershell-automation-and-remoting-a-c-love-story/) instead

Comment: Aren't you interested in RESTful web services?

Comment: if you totally have to use c# - WMI is the simplest as a whole - the simple problem with your code usually is if for example you have a user DOMAIN\User .. if you only specify "user"  etc.. or you dont have rights on the machine..

Comment: @BugFinder you mean instead of username="****"  i should use username="FB\\*****"?

Comment: depends on where the user is defined....

Comment: @BugFinder thank you your small point causes solving my problem. please add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using WMI you need to use a user account which as privileges on the remote machine

so, if you have PC1, and you log in as user1, and you try to login to PC2, its trying to log in as PC1\user1.. So you need to be specific about the username you login to the remote machine, or ensure that the user on the second machine.

You may need to send PC2\User1 to login on the remote machine as User1 on there as to it, its a whole different person